# How to label my diagrams in Tikz

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles

I found that the following code using the `tikz` package will draw a rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, my question is what do I need to do if I want to label the four points as `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`?

Comment: You can download the tikz manual (with lots of tutorials) at https://ctan.org/topic/pgf-tikz?lang=en

Comment: @JohnKormylo okay, thanks. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$A$};
\node[below right] at (4,0) {$B$};
\node[above right] at (4,4) {$C$};
\node[above left] at (0,4) {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Oh! It waseasy then :)